# referencing an external dll at runtime

Tags: c#, .net

Update: I have strongly named my DLL as suggested, but my codeBase tag does not seem to be having any effect. Fusion does not show my custom directory as one of the dll scan targets. Starting my service still throws a FileNotFoundException.

I have several exe's in sub folders of my projects root directory.  I need to place a DLL into the root directory and enable all of these exe's to reference it. So far I have edited my exe's app.config file as so:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="resources"
                            publicKeyToken="fe437a7f5a917214"
                            culture="neutral" />
          <codeBase version="1.0.0.0"
                    href="file:///c:/program files (x86)/root Directory/resources.dll"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

My exe has a reference set through the IDE with the "copy local" option set to false. Yet when I attempt to start my exe (it is a windows service), it errors and writes a windows event log throwing System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you really have a directory called `root Directory` in `c:\program files (x86)\`? Seems awfully unusual.

Comment: have you tried loading it with Assembly.Load() and the same path?

Comment: my exe is currently attempting to call Load() but the service doesn't start, so it never happens.

Comment: This can't work, private assemblies must be in a directory relative to the install directory.  Read the Remarks section in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb.aspx

Comment: "If the assembly is a private assembly, the codebase setting must be a path relative to the application's directory."

This means I can only have my DLL in sub directories of my EXE? This will not work for me.  What are my other options?

Comment: Give your assemblies a strong name, as noted in the link Hans gave.

Comment: @MichałPowaga - I wasn't referencing the `(x86)` extension, I know that exists, but naming a directory `root Directory` just seems odd.

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood you :-/. I'll delete this and the previous one comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
href="file:///c:/program files (x86)/root Directory/resources.dll"/>
```

needs to be

```
href="file:///c:\program files (x86)\root Directory\resources.dll"/>
```